# Ask for the name of a condition on commutator of two operators

Tags: terminology, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $T, S$ be two bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space. I wonder whether there is a standard way referring the following condition:

$$
\text{The commutator $[T, S]$ is in the Hilbert-Schmidt class.}
$$

Note that, if the Hilbert-Schmidt class is replaced by compact operator, then we call that $T$ and $S$ essentially commute.

Comment: I think that there is no special name for the mentioned condition. Usualy, for an ideal ${\mathcal I}$ (or even for an arbitrary set) of operators, one says that $S, T$ commute modulo ${\mathcal I}$ if $[T,S]\in {\mathcal I}$.

Comment: That is OK, then I will say that T, S commute modulo HS class.